# Create an NSDate from NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I use the following code to create an `NSDate` from string:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSLog(@"The date from string: %@", [df dateFromString:@"2012-01-31 01:32:30"]);
```

What I see in the result is:

```
The date from string: 2012-01-31 07:32:30 +0000
```

This is obviously not correct.
Do you know why it adds 6 hours to my result date and how to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`NSLog` of dates is not a good way to display dates with time zones, instead use an `NSDateFormatter` to get a string for the time zone desired.

`NSDate` is UTC based, the one true time that can be correctly displayed for any timezone with `NSDateFormatter`.

From the Apple `NSDate` docs:

> To parse strings containing dates and to generate string
>   representations of a date, you should use an instance of
>   NSDateFormatter using the methods dateFromString: and stringFromDate:
>   respectively—see “Date Formatters” for more details.

Example code:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:@"2012-01-31 01:32:30"];
NSLog(@"The date from string: %@", date);

NSString *stringFromDate = [df stringFromDate:date];
NSLog(@"stringFromDate: %@", stringFromDate);
```

NSLog output:

> The date from string: 2012-01-31 06:32:30 +0000
>   stringFromDate: 2012-01-31 01:32:30